# Cryptkeeper File Lost

Tags: encryption, cryptkeeper

I screwed up, and I need your help.

I maintained an encrypted folder on my secondary hard drive (created with cryptkeeper) which housed a lot of my personal financial data, official documents, etc. I forgot about the file when I did a clean install of kubuntu, and now I can't access the folder. Is there a way to regain access to it, or am I SOL?

Comment: just by installing "kubuntu clean" (never heard of that). Or what did you do with that? I thought cryptkeeper uses EncFS -> afaik a folder. You write "the file". What do you mean exactly.

Comment: sorry, clean install of kubuntu.

Basically, I had another distro of ubuntu, in which I created the encrypted folder using cryptkeeper. I then wanted to use KDE, so I installed kubuntu, wiping the old distro completely. I didn't think it would be an issue since the file was on my secondary hard drive, I figured I could just import the folder using cryptkeeper in kubuntu, and that is proving difficult.

Comment: `cryptkeeper` is in the Ubuntu repos - if you've tried installing this and still can't recover your file, there must be more to the story. Please update your question with details.  Errors you recieved when trying to unlock the file, etc. Anything that might help someone understand your actual problem.

Comment: I created the folder a while ago. The pathway to it SHOULD be /media/dan/Archives/Personal Archives. 

When I open cryptkeeper this is the process I've followed:
1) Import EncFS folder
2) type "/media/dan/Archives/Personal Archives" in to the location bar
3) Click forward
4) Receive error message "The selected folder is not an EncFS encrypted folder"